# SQL Statement issue , UPDATING the wrong information

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, sql-update, inner-join

I apologize in advance if this has been asked somewhere else. I have extensively looked for a solution but cannot find one.

I have a database that I am trying to update. I am using Microsoft Access to do this.

I have 1 table called products that has 4 columns as follows: categoryID, categoryName, productID and newName.

What I want is for the new name to be generated by taking the name from 'categoryName' where the 'categoryID' and 'productID' are equal.The problem is that my query updates the 'newName' column with the wrong information.

My SQL Query is as follows :

```
UPDATE products 
SET newName = categoryName 
WHERE productID LIKE categoryID
```

_
These are examples of my tables:

**This is what the table looks like before I run the query:**

```
TABLE NAME : products.
categoryID     categoryName     productID     newName
1              Kids             7             
2              Baby             5                       
3              Themes           4                      
4              General          4             
5              Neon Glow        5             
6              Costumes         4                 
7              1st Birthday     7
```

**This is what happens when I run the query:**

```
TABLE NAME : products.
categoryID     categoryName     productID     newName
1              Kids             7             Kids
2              Baby             5             Baby            
3              Themes           4             Themes          
4              General          4             General 
5              Neon Glow        5             Neon Glow
6              Costumes         4             Costumes        
7              1st Birthday     7             1st Birthday
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
TABLE NAME : products.
categoryID     categoryName     productID     newName
1              Kids             7             1st Birthday
2              Baby             5             Neon Glow           
3              Themes           4             General          
4              General          4             General
5              Neon Glow        5             Neon Glow
6              Costumes         3             Themes       
7              1st Birthday     7             1st Birthday
```

My query is currently checking if there two ID columns are equal and then copies the category name. 
I want the 'newName' field to be populated with the 'categoryName' that is in the same row as the 'categoryID' if the 'productID' is equal to that of the 'categoryID'.

Please assist me with finding the error in my SQL statement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag the question appropriately.  It says MS Access, but the tag is MySQL.  I removed that tag and added ms-access, but apparently it was changed back for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE p 
SET p.newName = p1.categoryName 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN products p1 ON p.productID = p1.categoryID
```

Comment: Hi there, when I try this I get an error.The error is as follows :" Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'p1.categoryName FROM products p INNER JOIN products p1 ON p.productID = p1.categoryID'.".

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
UPDATE products 
    SET newName = (select categoryName
                   from products as p2
                   where p2.productId = products.categoryID
                  );
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error. The error is as follows: " Operation must use an updateable query.".